# What does TLS Handshake Type 174 Mean?

Tags: networking, ssl

Out of curiosity, I spent some time looking through TCP dumps of an https web connection I made.  I have been able to make sense of most of it, but I am stuck on one particular TLS Record.  Here is the hex dump:

```
16 03 01 00 24 ae f5 83  cb 35 db dd 67 f5 bf 4a
c7 52 b5 16 56 59 52 40  fa 7b f8 f6 40 a7 13 74
0a f3 b0 6e 5b 4f 2b 88  a3
```

The previous Record is a Change Cipher Spec Record (i.e. Content Type 0x14) if that helps.  Also, I used wget to make the request.

As far as I can tell, this should follow the handshake subprotocol (16), uses TLS 1.0 (03 01), the message length is 36 Bytes (00 24).  And here is where I am stuck: what does the ae mean?!  At first I thought it might have something to do with SNI or some other TLS extension, but so far no luck there either.

Any help interpreting this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no HandshakeType with a value of 174.  The 174 shows up because the TLS connection just finished negotiating a cipher suite, and is now encrypting the record's payload!

Comment: It looks like it's probably the `finished` message in the handshake: "The Finished message is the first one protected with the just negotiated algorithms, keys, and secrets." [rfc5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.9)